# AutoCad - one layout to multiple pages PDF

Tags: export, autocad

My project is made with all pages (sheets) in one layout (screenshots in attachment).
I tried everything to export (or plot) the project in PDF with every page on different sheet (ready for printing) with no luck.

P.S. It looks like project is already organized in some grid system, but can anyone help me with solution on how to export every of those cells to one PDF sheet?

[image]
[image]

Comment: My understanding is AutoCAD is not set up to deal with this kind of situation natively.  You would need to write some kind of script that would re define your plot window and append the resulting pdf to an existing pdf file.  Alternatively you could print each one as a separate PDF then combine the individual PDF files.  Would depend on the pdf software you have available though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a command tool that executes a print to pdf command sequence.
Here's a ready command sequence for printing Landscape A4 PDF.

*^C^C-PLOT;Y;Model;autocad pdf (general documentation).pc3;ISO A4 (297.00 x 210.00 MM);M;L;N;Window;\RESUME;Fit;Center;Y;acad.ctb;Y;;\;Y;

but you will have to manually select the printing window for each cell and assign a new name for each file.

you will end with multiple pdf files which you can join them later in one file if you like.

Here's a picture for a similar custom command I used before

[image]